# Do apple panic logs contain confidential info?

Tags: security

If a panic log was put on something like paste bin or given to a third party, could its contents contain personal info/compromise the security of my system?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by a "panic log"? - I.e. could you further define what you mean by this. Are you talking about the contents of a kernel panic message only, or are you talking about the panic.log file on historic Mac OS X versions, or are you talking about something entirely different?

Comment: Without details as to what you consider your threat model to be - we can’t rightly answer this. What is your security / PII concern? Is it with TV device, watch, Mac, iPhone or other device? If you could edit this to show your research and narrow down to a specific OS this might not be so broad a question.

Answer (score 3):

What is confidential is relative - something might be confidential information for you, and for others it might not be. It is therefore entirely subjective.

So yes, in that sense, a panic log could contain confidential information.

However, if you by "panic log" mean a simple kernel panic message, then no - most ordinary users would not find that to be confidential information. Nor would they consider it as containing personal information or compromise the security of your system.

If you want to be completely pedantic about it - yes, there's an ever so slight risk of something you think is important being loaded into a register at just the time of the kernel panic. I.e. a register could in theory contain an IP address or perhaps 8 characters of your password. The latter being very improbably. However, they would look more or less indistinguishable from random bytes to an outside observer.

So - are you an home user battling a problem with a hardware peripheral causing kernel panics every now and then - and is requested to send the kernel panic to that manufacturer's support team - I wouldn't be worried at all.

But if you happen to have state secrets all over your computer and you are directly targeted by a foreign state that can trigger your computer to kernel panic at the most unfortunate times over and over again - while that enemy can read your kernel panics, but not otherwise what's display on your monitor - then yes, I would be slightly worried.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I was just asking because I gave my laptop to someone to get fixed and when I got it back it had paste bin open with my panic log on it and it just worried me as I wasn't sure what paste bin was and if the log could contain info that you wouldn't want out there

Comment: Yeah I wouldn’t worry about that - should be perfectly safe!

Answer (score 0):

Possibly, but it is very unlikely that enough information would be captured to provide much meaningful information. The kernel panic captures details about instructions occurring at the CPU. Apple has an old but detailed (and still relevant) explanation of how to interpret the panic log, here: https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/technotes/tn2063/_index.html